# How do I record from a Casio keyboard with different sounds/instruments using multi-tracking?

Tags: recording

How do I record different from a Casio keyboard to Audacity, where different sounds (bass, drums, piano, etc.) make up multiple tracks?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously any synth can be connected via a jack to a soundcard's audio input.

Your steps:

1. Connect your synth to your PC via audio cable, not USB or midi.
2. Run Audacity and set the audio params.
3. Add a new track and arm for recording. Set the appropriate audio channel.
4. Record the track using a sound of your choice.

For other tracks repeat p3-p4.

I would recommend using a DAW instead, Adobe Audition, Reaper, Pro Tools, Sony Acid, Fruity Loops, Cubase, or some other instead of Audacity.

Comment: I don't know if listing those counts as recommendations, but here is a more inclusive list of software that doesn't recommend any specifics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_music_software

Comment: And it's Audacity, not Audiocity.